# Connecting to Oracle server using Mysql Client

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have tried to connect to Oracle Express Edition 11g server using Mysql WorkBench but not able to connect and get this error ***Lost connection to MySQL server at reading initial communication packet***, so I want to know that can one connect to oracle server using Mysql client, its useful for everyone because I have googled much but doesn't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: post your config file and the code you are using to connect

Comment: Why are you trying to use MySQL Workbench to connect to an Oracle database?  MySQL Workbench is only for connecting to MySQL databases; you cannot use a MySQL client to connect to an Oracle database.  Use an Oracle client for that instead.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I know that, I can connect using Oracle Client, but I m in the curiosity to know that how one should connect using Mysql Client to Oracle Server, as we know that one should connect to MySQL server using SQL developer(Oracle Client).

Comment: SQL Developer isn't an Oracle client.  It uses JDBC to connect to a database, so it works with any database that has a JDBC driver.  An actual Oracle client won't talk to a MySQL database, so please don't be misled into thinking you can connect a MySQL client to an Oracle database.